# NtLoadDriver in windows 8 - privilege not held

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8

I'm trying to load driver in windows 8 using `NtLoadDriver`. And I've got on return of this function - `0xC0000061` (NTSTATUS value). Which means: **Privilege not held**. I created registry key and set all values. Also I'm running it as administrator. What can case such problems ?

Comment: You'll need to run with UAC elevation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even as an administrative user, some privileges are "disabled" by default and have to be explicitly enabled before they can be used. The privilege to load drivers (`SeLoadDriverPrivilege`) is one of these.

Enabling the privilege is achieved through the use of the [`AdjustTokenPrivileges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function at which point you should be able to load the driver successfully. There are plenty of examples online of how to do this correctly.

Comment: You missed "Also I'm running it as administrator" in the question.

Comment: @HansPassant - No, I didn't (hence "Even as an administrative user"). In order to use a privilege, it must be both present in the token (which it should be, since it's running as admin, although this assumes the token is an unrestricted elevated token, which your UAC answer would cover) *and* enabled. It's this second part that is likely the issue.